# Simulating a page visit in Python

Tags: python, web, bots

I would like to automate the following actions on a website seen from the server perspective:

1. User visits the website
2. User is authenticated via cookie
3. User clicks on an internal link

So basically it's a simple bot navigating a website in a predetermined way. How would I go about creating something like this in Python to be run on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Selenium webdriver, maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different approaches to this but I will list a few so you know what to search for:

1. Write a simple request with the cookie and python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/cookies/) library and the internal [`cookiejar`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.cookiejar.html)
2. Using Python + [Beautiful Soup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3)
3. Write a crawler with the [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) library to connect to a site and gather information across pages (following links it finds)
4. If you need to run Javascript, look at using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)